# How do dependencies work in Scala?

Tags: scala, sbt, akka

For my existing projects I am migrating from scalaVersion 2.10.5 to 2.11.7 and sbtVersion 1.13.9 also.

Current migrating project is **Sales**, it have **Sales-common, Sales-read, Sales-write** modules. It have one dependent project **Core**. But I don't have Core project code I have only already published artefact jars(I have myapp-core-read_2.10-2.2.33.jar, 2.10 is Scala version).

My project looks like this

> Sales
>
> ```
> common
>
>     build.sbt
>
> read
>
>     build.sbt
>
> write
>
>     build.sbt
>
> build.sbt
> ```

Till now, with scala 2.10.5 everything working fine using in real time also.

After change the version I run `sbt clean` and `sbt update`. I am getting Unresolved dependency issue like this:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: mycompany#myapp-core-read_2.11;2.2.33: not found
[warn]  :: mycomapny#myapp-core-write_2.11;2.2.33: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

My **Sales buld.sbt** is this:

```
name := "myapp-sales"

organization in ThisBuild := "com.mycompany"

scalaVersion in ThisBuild  := "2.11.7"

//crossScalaVersions in Thisq
//Build := List("2.10.5", scalaVersion.value)
//crossPaths := false

scalacOptions in Compile in ThisBuild ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-encoding", "utf8", "-language:postfixOps", "-language:implicitConVersions")

lazy val common = Project("myapp-sales-common", file("common"))

lazy val read = Project("myapp-sales-read", file("read")).configs(IntegrationTest).settings(Defaults.itSettings: _*).dependsOn(common, write)

lazy val write = Project("myapp-sales-write", file("write")).configs(IntegrationTest).settings(Defaults.itSettings: _*).dependsOn(common)


conflictWarning in ThisBuild := ConflictWarning.disable

parallelExecution in Test in ThisBuild := false

parallelExecution in IntegrationTest in ThisBuild := false

javacOptions in Compile in ThisBuild ++= Seq("-source", "1.6", "-target", "1.6")


//Remove SNAPSHOT check from the release process (for now until Squants gets a release)
releaseProcess := releaseProcess.value.filterNot(_ == ReleaseTransformations.checkSnapshotDependencies)
```

My **read** module **build.sbt**:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.mycompany"         %% "myapp-core-read"            % myappsales.CoreVersion            % "compile", // disable using the Scala version in output paths and artifacts,
  "com.mycompany"         %% "myapp-core-write"           % myappsales.CoreVersion            % "compile",
  "com.mycompany"         %% "myapp-registration-common"  % myappsales.RegistrationVersion    % "compile",
  "com.mycompany"         %% "myapp-load-common"          % myappsales.LoadVersion            % "compile",
  "com.mycompany"         %% "myapp-core-write-test"      % myappsales.CoreVersion            % "it, test",
  "com.mycompany"         %% "myapp-core-test"            % myappsales.CoreVersion            % "it, test"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe"               % "config"                                % myappsales.TypeSafeConfigVersion % "compile",
  "org.json4s"                 %% "json4s-native"                         % Versions.Json4s         % "compile",
  "io.spray"                    % "spray-routing"                         % Versions.Spray          % "compile",
  "com.typesafe.akka"          %% "akka-actor"                            % Versions.Akka           % "compile",
  "com.typesafe.akka"          %% "akka-remote"                           % Versions.Akka           % "compile"
    exclude ("io.netty", "netty")
)

//Assemby settings
test in assembly := {}
assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("play.api.libs.iteratee.**" -> "shade.play.api.libs.iteratee.@1")
    .inLibrary("play" % "play-iteratees_2.10" % "2.1-RC2")
    .inLibrary("org.reactivemongo" % "reactivemongo_2.10" % "0.8.1-SNAPSHOT"),
  ShadeRule.rename("scala.concurrent.stm.**" -> "shade.scala.concurrent.stm.@1")
    .inLibrary("org.scala-stm" % "scala-stm_2.10.0" % "0.6")
    .inLibrary("play" % "play-iteratees_2.10" % "2.1-RC2")
)

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case "application.conf" => MergeStrategy.concat
  case path => MergeStrategy.defaultMergeStrategy(path)
}

//Make assembly a publishable artifact
artifact in (
  Compile, assembly) := {
  val art = (artifact in (Compile, assembly)).value
  art.copy(`classifier` = Some("assembly"))
}

addArtifact(artifact in (Compile, assembly), assembly)
```

How can I make it work with existing myapp-core-read_2.10-2.2.33.jar jar?

Answer (score 3):

**Important note:** Scala 2.10 and 2.11 are not binary compatible so you will have to recompile the modules on which you depend

**Answer to question:**

This seems to be related to how SBT resolves dependencies. When you declare a dependency like so:

```
"com.mycompany" %% "myapp-core-read" % myappsales.CoreVersion
```

The `%%` part in the declaration means that SBT will automatically append the scala version to the library name, so your dependency becomes

```
group: com.mycompany
artifactId: myapp-core-read_2.11
version: `your version`
```

It seems that your `myapp-core-read` was not compiled with scala `2.11` thus SBT can't find the correct version.

You can avoid this by using `%` and applying the correct suffix manually, so your dependency would become:

```
"com.mycompany" % "myapp-core-read_2.10" % myappsales.CoreVersion
```

Having said that, I think scala 2.10 and 2.11 are not binary compatible so you might have to recompile the `myapp-core-read` module with 2.11.

Comment: WOW, great information, Almost solved my problem. thanks **Denis Rosca**.

Comment: I removed one `%` but it not looking for **"myapp-core-read_2.10" % myappsales.CoreVersion**. it looking for **"myapp-core-read" % myappsales.CoreVersion**.  Could you please help me how to use existing jars in local repository.

Comment: @Ravi If you remove one `%` you have to add the suffix yourself. So in the dependency declaration you have to change `myapp-core-read` to `myapp-core-read_2.10`.

Anyway, as I said in the answer, you will most likely have to recompile the myapp-core-read with 2.11 as well.